# Displaying items or unit for purchase conversion in game

Tags: decision-making

Consider a game where you collect items of two sizes, A represents 1 unit (normal), B represents 3 of the same units (Special Golden item).

When the player runs out of time, the panel indicates your gathering.

If the player can buy more time, which would be more convincing to convert the purchase:

1xB 3xA

Or

6xA

Since they are the same quantity, is it better to show the accurate inventory or the larger number?

In the end, the count is added to a pot so there is no more any representation of the collected items. So it is solely visible on the purchase moment.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of characteristics the item to buy in your game has.

Generally speaking, your question is:

- Quantity makes Quality?

[image]

or

- The Quality is independent of Quantity

[image]

My personal opinion is that in the case of games in terms of winning, obtaining or buying, quantity is more motivating than quality:

[image]

Unless you make a super-ultra-mega-top design for the group of objects, in this case the motivation is to get the "trophy" more than the content:

[image]

#### Update after the comment

Usually in games it's difficult to get items, so the greater the loss, the more frustration, I would not hesitate to show the total amount of items lost (6A). Then, this will be the normal transaction:

- You just lost quantity: 6A and we offer you buying the same: 6A.

And this is what you can specially offer in your game:

- You lost 6A (quantity), in exchange we suggest you to buy 1B (quantity plus quality)

In terms of number of items it's the same but perceptively the second option offers something better, two elements at the same price

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Actually, the items are normal/gold. So you collect normal items worth 1 and you collect gold items worth 3. When comes the summary, would it convert better if I tell the player "if you don't pay, you will lose 1 gold and 3 normal" or "if you don't pay, you will lose 6 normal". In the end, all are converted to single units added to a pot. The question is purely about what visual would work better. Based on what you say, second solution is quantity (you lose 6) and would convert better purchase.

Comment: Answer updated with a "draft" conclusion ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a question that should be tested. Small details in purchase conversion are still very speculative and something like this you'd want as large of a quantitative test as you can get.

Comment: Indeed, we would perform AB test on this but I was just curious if there were psychological tests (i'm pretty sure there are) done on this. I'm thinking marketing where you would " Get 2 boxes of 10" or "Get 20".